# After Effects crash causing graphics driver issues

Tags: adobe-after-effects

[image]

So here's the error message I get when AE crashes. It happens kind of randomly and always my notebook freezes completely and the screen goes black and I need to do a hard reboot. 
Any ideas what's causing it? Lack of RAM maybe? I do have 8GB.

Comment: Just a guess.. but maybe contact Adobe support as it tells you to?

Comment: I did, but no response. That's why I wanted to know, if someone here had a similar issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please specify which operating system are you using win/mac. I know some solution for win operating system.

This solution is only for windows operating system!
- close AE, if it is already open
- type %temp% in the RUN command box. You will be taken to system temporary folder. 
- delete the files in this temp directory.
- run AE and check if the problem occurs.

Comment: it's Win 8. And you are right, the temp folder was quite full (250mb) even though I empty it regularly. Didn't have the error yet so far. Will update if it happens again by any chance. Thanks.

Comment: AE also creates cache files in the "C:\Users\<yourpcname>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Common" You can clean this cache files by going in the AE menu -> Edit>preferences>media & disk cache" and click on the "Clean database and disk cache". This should solve the problem.

Comment: Check out this link too! :)
http://creativedojo.net/clean-after-effects-disk-cache/